# Bind to slapd ldap server using uid instead of cn

Tags: ldap, openldap, ruby, slapd

I'm trying to connect to an LDAP server running slapd, using the net_ldap ruby gem. I'm able to perform the bind action using the cn of the user, but I need to use the uid.

The LDAP server was created by ClearOS and is otherwise untouched, standard configuration.

Here's my ruby code:

```
  Net::LDAP.new(
    {
      host: "10.1.1.3",
      port: 389,
      base: "dc=company,dc=lan",
      auth: {
        method: :simple, 
        username: 'cn=Andrew Faraday,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=company,dc=lan',
        password: "secret"
      }
    }
  ).bind
```

That works fine, but what I really want to do is log in using the uid rather than the cn, e.g.

```
        username: 'uid=ajfaraday,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=company,dc=lan',
```

Here's the result of a successful ldap search (fairly heavily redacted):

```
dn: cn=Andrew Faraday,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=edge,dc=lan

uidNumber: 2004

gidNumber: 63000

homeDirectory: /home/ajfaraday

clearAccountStatus: enabled

sambaAcctFlags: [U          ]

sambaDomainName: company

sambaBadPasswordCount: 0

sambaBadPasswordTime: 0

uid: ajfaraday

givenName: Andrew

sn: Faraday

objectClass: top

objectClass: posixAccount

objectClass: shadowAccount

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

objectClass: clearAccount

objectClass: sambaSamAccount

cn: Andrew Faraday

loginShell: /bin/bash
```

I've spent a few days digging through slap config files, manuals and old (like, over a decade old) questions on this and I'm coming up blank. I've tried variants on all of these things:

- Define a rule to build the dn differently for each user.
- Allow authorisation rights on the uid attribute.
- Set up an authz-regexp or sasl-regexp to convert input to a search string looking for uid.

None of these appear to have the desired effect. The regexp attributes appear to do nothing at all.

Comment: You might change the `DN`'s in the LDAP database to use `uid` as the leftmost `RDN`. Or do you wish to log in sometimes by `uid` and sometimes by `cn`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I'd be happy to always log in by `uid`, but I can't find out how to configure that.

Answer (score 2):

In `LDAP` there are two ways to authenticate: the simple mechanism and `SASL`.

The simple mechanism you are using requires you to bind against an exact Distinguished Name. So if you want to use your username instead of your fullname you have to change the `DN`, by using the following `LDIF` instructions:

```
dn: cn=Andrew Faraday, ou=Users, ou=Accounts, dc=company, dc=lan
changetype: modrdn
newrdn: uid=ajfaraday
deleteoldrdn: 0
```

However the `SASL` mechanisms are more flexible and you can map any login to an `LDAP` entry. You can also perform an `LDAP` search to find your `DN`. E.g., if you add the rewrite rules:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAuthzRegexp
olcAuthzRegexp: gidNumber=([0-9]*)\+uidNumber=([0-9]*),cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
    ldap:///ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=edge,dc=lan??sub?(&(gidNumber=$1)(uidNumber=$2))
```

you can locally authenticate to `LDAP` through the Unix socket:

```
ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL
```

**Remark**: You need to **restart** the server after changing the `olcAuthzRegexp` attribute for it to be taken into account.